# Select all tables row of dataset that lesson is equal 2 specific values

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a database which has a table called `MainData`. The format of the data is as follow:

```
ID  Lesson  Time    Score
1   C       165     4
1   E       190     3
1   H       195     3
1   I       200     4
2   A       100     2
2   B       150     5
2   D       210     2
2   E       110     4
3   D       130     5
3   E       190     5
3   H       210     4
3   I       160     4
3   J       110     4
4   E       120     3
4   H       150     4
4   J       170     4
```

I want to write a command that. Let me explain by an example

Example:

If `Lesson` is equal `E` and `I` (in this case `ID 3` has this condition), the command returns all the rows for that specific ID. In this dataset more than one ID can have this condition.The thing that I need is to return all rows of these specific IDs.

BTW, mydataset is access.

Your help is appriciated.

The thing that I have tried already...

```
private void btn_recom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
   command.Connection = connection;
   private void GetRows()
   {
       // Get the DataTable of a DataSet.
       DataTable table = dsDataSet.Tables["MainData"];
       DataRow[] rows = table.Select();
       // Print the value one column of each DataRow.

   }
}
```

Comment: So, are you use ADO.Net to connect to your DB?  Or are you using a Linq provider?  Maybe you could show some code where you have attempted to do this yourself.

Comment: @juharr, I am using Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL would do the job although its a little inefficient:

```
SELECT * FROM MainData WHERE ID IN
(SELECT T1.ID
FROM MainData AS T1 INNER JOIN MainData AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Lesson="E" AND T2.Lesson="I"
GROUP BY T1.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks @Johanness but it does not return any rows. Also would you please explan what are **T**

Comment: T1 is a secodn instance of the MainData Table: ... FROM MainData AS T1.. means "Take an Instance of MainData, and because I have several of them, name this one T1". I tried this SQL in Access with your Table and it worked - How did you try to implement it?

Comment: Hello @Johanness. I put the whole question in following link.I appriciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302712/why-the-targetpoint-value-is-0

Comment: Thats a totally different thing that you have overthere than I suggested. And please update or expand the original question in this thread instead of posing a new one. Also There is no way for anyone to see what you want in the new question.

Comment: Sorry @Johanness. I forgot to edit the uploaded script. I just fixed it and may you check it again