# Query to select all rows with a condition

Tags: c#, jquery, ms-access

I need to make a query that select all rows belong to a `ID` from the datatable where `Lesson` from that `ID` has two specific values. For example `ID` 2 and 3 have lessons D and E that I want to take all the rows of `ID` 2 and `ID` 3.

My data is in `MS Access`.

MY Programming language is `C#`.

I already try to write some a query

```
"SELECT * FROM MainData WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM MainData GROUP BY ID HAVING (Lesson ='" + txtbox_startsubject.Text + "' and '" + TargetPoint + "'))";
```

The format of data:

```
ID  Lesson  Time    Score
1   C       165     4
1   E       190     3
1   H       195     3
1   I       200     4
2   A       100     2
2   B       150     5
2   D       210     2
2   R       10      3
2   E       110     4
3   D       130     5
3   E       190     5
3   H       210     4
3   I       160     4
3   J       110     4
4   E       120     3
4   H       150     4
4   J       170     4
```

Comment: I don't quite understand... what are the parameters? ID 2/3 or Lessons D/E or both? What is the expected result from your example data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all tables row of dataset that lesson is equal 2 specific values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287881/select-all-tables-row-of-dataset-that-lesson-is-equal-2-specific-values)