# Why the targetpoint value is 0

Tags: c#

the question are:

1-Why when I want to use the value `TargetPoint` in the Query line it always return 0.

2-I have one form (let's say form 1), that user select some information, and to get some other information and insert in the same form (form 1), user will be guided to another form to anser some question and come back again to the form 1. BUt the problem is when user come back to form one, those information are deleted and he needs to insert those information again.

Any help will be great.

```
    namespace LLL
        {
            public partial class LearnerForm : Form
            {
                public string TargetPoint;
                private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
                public LearnerForm()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\ds.accdb";
                    lbl_welcome.Text = "Welcome " +Login.name +"!";
                    txtbox_startsubject.Text = diagnostic_evaluation.startpoint;

                }

                private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                    //MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + txtbox_user.Text);
                }

                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
                //static string TargetPoint = null;
                public void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    diagnostic_evaluation F1 = new diagnostic_evaluation();
                    F1.Show();
                    //string TargetPoint = null;
                    if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "A";
                    }
                    if (checkBox2.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "B";
                    }
                    if (checkBox3.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "C";
                    }
                    if (checkBox4.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "D";
                    }
                    if (checkBox5.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "E";
                    }
                    if (checkBox6.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "F";
                    }
                    if (checkBox7.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "G";
                    }
                    if (checkBox8.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "H";
                    }
                    if (checkBox9.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "I";
                    }
                    if (checkBox10.Checked)
                    {
                        TargetPoint = "J";
                    }            

                }

                private void btn_recom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    DataTable InteractionData = new DataTable();
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MainData WHERE ID IN (SELECT T1.ID FROM MainData AS T1 INNER JOIN MainData AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID WHERE (T1.Lesson='" + txtbox_startsubject.Text + "' AND T2.Lesson='"+TargetPoint+"') GROUP BY T1.ID)";   
                    OleDbDataAdapter maindata = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                    DataTable interaction = new DataTable();
                    DataTable recommendation = new DataTable();
                    maindata.Fill(interaction);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = interaction;
                    connection.Close();
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: You never assign value `0` to `TargetPoint`. Make sure you are posted all related code. Navigating between forms should be separate question.

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy. since i already tried with that and it did exactly the same

Comment: I doubt that this is a valid SQL syntax _(Lesson ='" + txtbox_startsubject.Text + "' and '" + TargetPoint+"'))";_ Where is the fieldname before the TargetPoint value?

Comment: thanks @Steve, I tried to work on the query and make it more clear but the point is target point will be returened as 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "Targetpoint will be returned as 0"? Did you check the query string (debug print)?

Comment: I cant see anything in this code that suggests a problem. I ran a few tests myself and couldn;t replicate the problem you are having. When you say "returns 0" do you mean the query returns with nothing, or the variable itself is 0